# How to make stripe of particular width under text in table cell

Tags: html

I got a little problem. I'm making table of chemical elements in HTML. I have separated the whole table into sections which mean different types /groups of chemical elements. But....there are some metals that are called differently, e.g. alkaline metals, but they are still in metal group. So I wanted to make whole table cell in gray , but also make a light green stripe in the middle to see, that its alkaline metal.
Heres a piece of code:

```
<td class="metal">
    <a href="aboutelement">
        <strong>Li</strong>
        <span class="atomicnumber">3</span>
        <em>Lithium</em>
        <span class="atomicweight">6.939</span>
    </a>
</td>
```

I just want to make green stripe(in the middle with concrete width ), that is behind text of t. cell, which wont affect the layout of the text and the gray color on the background. I can send you more detailed version of this with CSS, but I think youll understand what I want to make.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read
[what this site is about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and 
"[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" 
before asking a question.

Comment: You sounded like you want to make a simple border to show demarcations among the lists of Elements, and the border should be a one sided border that will seem like a line for demarcation ???

Comment: Given the two comments left so far, I'd suggest adding an image showing the end-result you're looking for. Also, if you've made an attempt it always helps if you show the code that failed, and explain what you expected it to do and how it failed to achieve those goals.

Answer (score 0):

```css
td {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #ddd 15%, lime 16%, lime 84%, #ddd 85%);
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

a {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="aboutelement">
                <strong>Li</strong><br>
                <span class="atomicnumber">3</span><br>
                <em>Lithium</em><br>
                <span class="atomicweight">6.939</span>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: https://www.google.sk/search?client=ms-android-xiaomi&biw=360&bih=315&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=KggVW_T9MsvUwQKjxLHYBA&q=taosi++psp&oq=taosi++psp&gs_l=mobile-gws-wiz-img.3...2693.10051..10882...4....182.2315.21j4......0....1.......3..0j35i39j0i19j0i10i19j0i5i30i19.Lqqjwbh9t9c%3D#imgrc=fPuLSDii89U9xM:

Comment: Updated the sample.